# While running the application on android device, controls do not display properly as designed in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been facing this issue while creating any android program/app using android studio. Whatever I design in android studio, it is not displaying properly as designed in android studio while running the app on my phone. 
In short, sometimes size and the places of the controls get changed while running the app on my android phone. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which type of UI element you are using and perhaps share some screenshots as examples? There are many reasons that this could be occurring; e.g. if you're using `ConstraintLayout` without sufficient constraints applied (there's an IDE warning for that), or if you are for instance editing a `layout-landscape` file but viewing on device in portrait. Also different display densities can cause things to appear differently - ensure you're using the same in IDE as your device if you want to see 1:1.

Comment: Could you show some code for a layout that you are having questions about?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of the difference in screen sizes of your preview and your physical phone  . I've recently started using constraint layout and I think it's the best so far, a bit confusing at first but easy to understand it, it even has an option for percentage of width/height of the total screen for a view. Try that out.